# WinRT, Metro, Win8 remember list position w/o animation

Tags: windows-runtime

I have a listview which i reload when i click on an item. I want to remember the scroll position so I use the following code:

```
private double scrollPosition;
public void SaveListPosition()
{
     scrollPosition = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
}

public void ScrollToSavedPosition()
{        
     scrollViewer.ChangeView(0, scrollPosition, null, false);
}
```

Its working fine, but it shows the scrolling. After I change the ChangeView method's disableAnimation parameter to true it doesn't show scrolling as expected, but it completely messes up list positions and doesn't scroll to the element that I clicked.

So questions are:

1) is this a bug in winrt?

2) can I override the ChangeView's animation so it will instantly scroll exactly like supplying true for the disableAnimation parameter?

3) Any other solution?